# Is it possible to use custom maps on Sigma ROX 12?

Tags: bike-computer

I wonder if it's possible to somehow upload custom maps to Sigma ROX 12 bike computer? The default map that is available on it for my country is not very good, so I want to customize it.

p.s.
When I say "maps" I mean maps and not routes.

Comment: So what country do you live in? Give an example of what kind of custom map you're looking for.

Comment: I live in canada. It works fine for me to do. don't know how, but it does!!

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the specs of the ROX12 it should be possible to store custom map data on a compatible SD card.

[image: ROX12 USER PDF]

[image: More PDF Info]
[image: Available Countries]

The device itself seems to use OSM format, this is Open Street Format that can be downloaded from either 
[Open Street Map](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=11/48.4533/-4.4989)

Or

[More Open Street Map Info](https://planet.openstreetmap.org/)

According to the manual [ROX12 User Manual](https://www.sigmasport.com/en/images/pdf/SIGMA-ROX%2012-Manual-WEB-EN.pdf) you should be able to select custom maps from within the device. You will however need a PC of some sort to download the maps and place them on the SD Card, also note the maximum SD Card is 128GB so you want your custom maps being to big.
The advantage of using the first Open Street Map website i linked to is you can pretty much pick any size map, if it gives you an error of maximum export size exceeded you can easily make the map smaller just by dragging your mouse over the page.

Hopefully this helps the OP achieve what they need.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Rox12 and can tell you you cannot use OSM maps (like with Garmin). Sigma post-processes them before you can use them, so you are “limited” to the set given in Dan K’s answer. I needed Laos and Cambodia, but these are not available.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this review: https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2018/06/sigma-rox-12-0-sport-cycling-gps-in-depth-review.html. His in-depth review states you can create custom maps using Komoot, Strava and AllTrails.

Comment: This is incorrect information, the device only can import routes from those services, not maps.

Comment: You are correct. I should have asked the OP what they meant by a custom map and what country they reside in.